# Why do my App crashes when the AppTheme is changed

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android, android-statusbar

My app crashes on launch after I changed the `AppTheme` from `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">` to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`

Following is the 'HomeActivity.kt'

```
class HomeActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportActionBar
        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val window = window
        window.statusBarColor = R.drawable.app_gradient_color_background

        binding.navView.background = null

        supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this@HomeActivity,
                R.drawable.app_gradient_color_background
            )
        )

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.nav_home,
                R.id.nav_orders,
                R.id.nav_cart
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)

        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        doubleBackToExit()
    }
}
```

Following is the 'Logcat'

```
2021-11-23 02:04:20.714 11275-11275/com.abc.xyz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.abc.xyz, PID: 11275
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.xyz/com.abc.xyz.ui.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3835)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4011)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.abc.xyz.ui.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:47)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
```

Please help me fix this error.

**To fix:**

I added the following in the `xml` layout file

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"/>
```

and  the following in the `onCreate` of 'HomeActivity.kt'

`setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbarHome)`

But the end result is not as I expected.

1- I can't see a toolbar at the top
2- The colour of the `BottomNavigationView` is changed to dark when the `Dark mode` is 'ON', I don't want that to happen. I want the colour of it white always.

Following is the 'activity_home.xml'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp""/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Show Categories"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"
        app:maxImageSize="56dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fab_image"
        app:tint="@null" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Following is what I have in the 'HomeFragment.kt` before I create my own Toolbar. How can I make my new toolbar available in the 'HomeFragment'?

```
   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu)
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
```

Edit:

NOTE: I just noticed that the issue regarding menu icon colour, icons are white when the 'Dark Mode' is ON and black when it's OFF. I wanted this to be white always.

When I change `fragment` to `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` app crashes with the below error. The error `com.abc.xyz.ui.activities.HomeActivity.onCreateHomeActivity.kt:62)` pointing at `val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.xyz/com.abc.xyz.ui.activities.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.abc.xyz.ui.activities.HomeActivity@2ed3cdc does not have a NavController set on 2131296976
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3835)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4011)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.abc.xyz.ui.activities.HomeActivity@2ed3cdc does not have a NavController set on 2131296976
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:61)
        at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
        at com.abc.xyz.ui.activities.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.kt:62)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3808)
```

I added `app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"` to change the colour of the title as this was changed to black when I added the new custom toolbar. However, I am not able to change the colour of the menu item (search, settings) and the overflow icon in the `toolbar`. As you can see in both the images below, it's white and when I run the app they are black. Could you tell me where I am supposed to make the changes?

'home_menu.xml'

[image]

@drawable/ic_search

[image]

Comment: Because using NoActionBar Theme removes the default ActionBar, and `supportActionBar` will return null in this case

Comment: OK. How can I deal with it in my case, please?

Comment: You should not reference supportActionBar at all unless you create your own ToolBar in the layout >> then use setSupportActionBar(myToolbar) before using it to avoid NPE like in `supportActionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(
            ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                this@HomeActivity,
                R.drawable.app_gradient_color_background
            )
        )`

Comment: @Zain I have made some changes in the code, can you check my question as I have updated it with the changes I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the original question is fixed by adding a customized toolBar to act as the `supportActionBar`

> 1- I can't see a toolbar at the top

Because it's obscured by the `fragment` (i.e it's behind it), to fix this add the toolBar & the fragment into a `ConstraintLayout` and adjust the constraint so that they not overlapped:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottom_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
        app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="50dp">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_new"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="Show Categories"
        android:scaleType="center"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"
        app:maxImageSize="56dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/fab_image"
        app:tint="@null" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/app_gradient_color_background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar_home"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

- Also no need to the top margin of the toolbar, so `android:layout_marginTop="24dp"` is removed.
- This `app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_appbar"` need to be removed from the `fragment`, it only required in the fab to anchor to the bottom bar.
- Change the `fragment` to `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` as `fragment` here is deprecated.

> 2- The colour of the BottomNavigationView is changed to dark when the Dark mode is 'ON', I don't want that to happen. I want the colour
> of it white always.

If you have a night version of the themes.xml file; please remove it; if not fixed; please share this file

Comment: Thank you, almost solved the issues but I have a little bit more issues. which I have added in the question after 'Edit'. Hope you wouldn't mind helping me fix them too. Anyways, I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @Codist For the error try to replace `val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)` with `val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        navHostFragment.navController`

Comment: For the icon try to add `android:tint="#FFFFFF"` to the vector

Comment: It didn't work. I created a new vector image and selected white colour while creating it and that too appeared black. However, another icon in the menu appeared white though.

Comment: Do you have a night version of colors.xml?

Comment: Because I do not know the proper implementation of the Night Mode, I removed it and now am using `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">`

Comment: Just to make sure I mean colors.xml not themes.xml.. Can you also please open a new question of this; hopefully guys can help you out; and I will try to reproduce this issue in my side